# ribbon global configuration it dosn't work

Tags: ribbon

I want to use `appliaction.properties` configuration ribbon's `ConnectTimeOut` and `ReadTimeOut` global ,example:

```
ribbon.ConnectTimeOut
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: please try to be more descriptive with the example of your code

Comment: `<clientname>.ribbon.ConnectTimeout=2000` can work, but `ribbon.ConnectTimeout=2000` doesn't work, i have 20 services,i want to gobal configuration,now  I can only focus on each service.